# What to answer if a client says "Sorry for late reply" in e-mail?

Tags: email

I got a reply from a client, but it was almost one week late. How can I respond to him politely? I don't think saying *"No Problem"* or *"It's all right"* is good. He said in the mail that he is *"Sorry for the delay caused"*.

What polite words should I use to go ahead with the current work?

Comment: @Vilmar- Thanks for edit. Can you please also answer me? It would be good to reply asap.

Comment: I'd say that this is the territory of http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: You don't -have- to respond to his apology. You can simply reply the time-frame you will go ahead with the work. IMHO that is more professional.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette, not the English language as such

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Sorry for this. I did not know about it. Will take care of this next time. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @trex: The advice in myol's comment and Darpan's answer is sound. In a face-to-face context, where you might *have* to respond to the apology, the standard response is *"**Don't mention it**"*. In a written context you're not obliged to respond at all - so you can simply *follow that advice yourself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If his delay affected something on your side then you may write about the progress of last week and what was expected from him (a reply on time, in this case; but be polite about it).

I could tell exact things to say, but I am not aware of the context.
However, it is advisable to not to mention it until unless his delay has caused some problems on your front or you don't want to notify him that delay is not acceptable.